# Where can I find an AS3 tool for Coloring Drawings?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I know you are all expert, and it's possible someone can help-me.

I'm developing a coloring website for kids, so I need some AS3 Coloring tool, or a class that helps in this.

I could do one by myself but I have no idea how a tool like that works. One way would be to have shapes behind the black lines, but this way I think would be much harder.

What I need is a tool, where I can use any png 32 bits files.

This tool: http://www.nocircleno.com/graffiti/examples/2.x/graffiti_advanced_demo.html
is almost what I need, expect the fact that the files with the drawing must be swf format.

Someone knows where can I find something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of any tools but I'd look at importing the PNG as bitmapdata and using the drawing API to build your brush and shape tools.  Here's a good example for the flood fill: http://www.multimediacollege.be/2010/04/optimizing-the-floodfill-method/

If I come across a library or example that has this functionality I'll post a link here.